# Threaded Brass adapter leak

Tags: pipe, pex, cpvc

A pair of adapters is bridging [CPVC](https://www.homedepot.com/p/ProLine-3-4-in-CPVC-Slip-x-Brass-FIP-Adapter-164-314NL/312763921) to [PEX](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Apollo-3-4-in-Brass-PEX-Barb-x-3-4-in-Male-Pipe-Thread-Adapter-APXMA3434/301541030).  The pair is coupled through threaded brass: PTFE Teflon tape was applied.  There is a very slight leak in the brass threading.  Any suggestions remedy the threaded brass is appreciated.

I am tempted to find a single adapter to bridge the CPVC to PEX, however I am hoping that the threaded brass leak-fix is simpler.

**Update:** the threaded brass adapters were removed in favor of a [Lowe's CPVC to PEX](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Genova-3-4-in-dia-Adapter-CPVC-Fittings/1001101564?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-google-_-lia-_-142-_-potablepipefittings-_-1001101564-_-0&placeholder=null&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvcma7MP26wIVq9SzCh3NsQkAEAYYAyABEgL1_vD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) adapter.  Unfortunately the [Home Depot Unicorn adapter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Apollo-3-4-in-Brass-PEX-A-Barb-x-3-4-in-CPVC-Straight-Adapter-EPXCPVC34/305469331) was 60 miles.

Comment: A pair?. More info is needed.

Comment: @blacksmith37 The leaky brass PEX adapter: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Apollo-3-4-in-Brass-PEX-Barb-x-3-4-in-Male-Pipe-Thread-Adapter-APXMA3434/301541030

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference (currently, it used to favor tape more) is to use PTFE pipe dope (paste) rather than tape for threaded joint sealing. I generally have fewer problems that way.

It's also become needful to closely examine threaded fittings as many in the current era are poorly made and may be difficult or impossible to seal due to thread defects that should never have made it out of the factory.

These two things may not be unrelated. It's quite possible that better-quality thread machining meant that tape really did work better in the past. Or it may just be that when tape first came out, there was no PTFE dope, there was just dope, from the dark ages.

After that, crank it up more, but it's quite possible to ruin things by overtightening, too.